# Cucumber test scenarios running in parallel?

Tags: multithreading, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I've couple test features in my project and so far i'm running them in parallel using runner classes with thread count.. but the problem here is optimising execution time because on of these threads taking longer time to finish test scenarios

Is there any better approach to execute test scenarios in parallel??

Any help.. much appreciated!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute cucumber feature file parallel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41034116/how-to-execute-cucumber-feature-file-parallel)

Comment: [Courgette-JVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42513907/how-to-run-cucumber-jvm-test-scenarios-in-parallel-using-gradle) worked fine for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Courgette-JVM

It has added capabilities to run cucumber tests in parallel on a feature level or on a scenario level.

It also provides an option to automatically re-run failed scenarios.

Usage

```
@RunWith(Courgette.class)
@CourgetteOptions(
    threads = 10,
    runLevel = CourgetteRunLevel.SCENARIO,
    rerunFailedScenarios = true,
    showTestOutput = true,
    cucumberOptions = @CucumberOptions(
            features = "src/test/resources/features",
            glue = "steps",
            tags = {"@regression"},
            plugin = {
                    "pretty",
                    "json:target/courgette-report/courgette.json",
                    "html:target/courgette-report/courgette.html"}
    ))
    public class RegressionTestSuite {
    }
```

Comment: When I try to run with Courgette I get the next error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/cucumber/core/snippets/SnippetType. Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.cucumber.core.snippets.SnippetType

Comment: check your runner class and steps are defined correctly in project structure

Answer (score 0):

Try using [QAF gherkin](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/gherkin_client.html) it runs scenario in parallel rather than feature. you need to use factory class provided by the framework and configure your execution using testNG xml. Below is the sample config file:

```
<test name="Gherkin-QAF-Test" parallel="methods">
   <parameter name="step.provider.pkg" value="com.qmetry.qaf.automation.impl.step.qaf" />
   <parameter name="scenario.file.loc" value="resources/features" />
   <classes>
      <class name="com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.client.gherkin.GherkinScenarioFactory" />
   </classes>
</test>
```

Above configuration will run scenarios available in feature files under `resources/features` in parallel.