# How to run cucumber jvm test scenarios in parallel using Gradle?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, gradle, cucumber-jvm, qaf

I couldn't find best solution for running cucumber test scenarios in parallel using gradle

The best possible solution found so far is [this](https://github.com/sukesh15/cucumber-jvm-parallel-generator).. but I can't run it locally successfully

Any help much appreciated!!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at [Courgette-JVM](https://github.com/prashant-ramcharan/courgette-jvm)

You can execute this with a gradle task.

It has added capabilities to run cucumber tests in **parallel** on a **feature level** or on a **scenario level**.

It also provides an option to automatically re-run failed scenarios.

**Usage**

```
@RunWith(Courgette.class)
@CourgetteOptions(
    threads = 10,
    runLevel = CourgetteRunLevel.SCENARIO,
    rerunFailedScenarios = true,
    showTestOutput = true,
    cucumberOptions = @CucumberOptions(
            features = "src/test/resources/features",
            glue = "steps",
            tags = {"@regression"},
            plugin = {
                    "pretty",
                    "json:target/courgette-report/courgette.json",
                    "html:target/courgette-report/courgette.html"}
    ))
    public class RegressionTestSuite {
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Prashant Ramcharan!! I'll take a look.

Comment: Unable to download the jar from maven or grade??

Comment: The JAR is on jcenter. In your build file - add jcenter to your repository.

Comment: In your build.gradle add this:

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

Comment: `/gradlew regressionSuite` is not running any tests.. it's simply giving me build success!! Any idea??

Comment: Where is the test class located in your project, is it on your test class path? Is the class name RegressionTestSuite? Note: I will add an example project soon! Watch the repo if you still interested.

Comment: it's in `/src/test/resources` and specified `include '**/RegressionTestSuite.class'` in build task!! with correct name.

Comment: The RegressionTestSuite class needs to be in src/test/java. Your feature files should be in src/test/resources

Comment: One more question: how about passing courgette options from command line like for ex: tags ("~@WIP") ??

Comment: Courgette uses JUnit to execute the tests and currently I've not included a Courgette CLI runner. 

Having said that, you can still specify multiple tags in the runner itself like so: tags = { "@regression", "~@WIP" }

Comment: is it possible to include project name, version and environmental details in courgette reports (FYI: I've added question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64331536/courgette-jvm-to-include-project-name-version-and-environment-in-the-reports)

Comment: @PrashantRamcharan - looks good - are there any plans to address CVSS vulnerabilities? We cant use this in our organization until these are addressed.

Comment: @Plaiska all security vulnerabilities have been addressed in version 5.8.0

Comment: @prashant ramcharan - we were able to import courgette in our organization , all vulnerabilities are indeed addressed. Thank you

Comment: @PrashantRamcharan I have sucessfully added the Courgette in my test runner class, but the issue is when execution happens, its not able to find the stepdefinationas and throws error. features = "classpath:features", glue = "stepDefinations",

Answer (score 0):

You should try [gherkin client](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/gherkin_client.html) of QMetry Automation Framework. By using it you can run individual scenario in parallel. You will get features like TestNG xml run configuration, [detailed reporting](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/qaf_reporting.html), parallel execution, step listener and many more.

In order to convert existing cucumber-jvm project to QAF following are the stpes:

- Download blank project [QAF-bank-project ANT+IVY](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-blank-project) or [qaf-blank-project-gradle](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-blank-project-gradle) or [qaf-blank-project-maven](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-blank-project-maven)
- Copy your features files into scenario directory
- Copy your java src files into src directory
- Place `@QAFTestStepProvider` annotation at class defining cucumber steps
- Create XML configuration file and run. You will find sample xml configuration file under config dir. For Gherkin your config file should look like below:

> ```
> <test name="Gherkin-QAF-Test">
>    <parameter name="step.provider.pkg" value="your.pkg.where.steps.defined" />
>    <parameter name="scenario.file.loc" value="resources/features" />
>    <classes>
>       <class name="com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.client.gherkin.GherkinScenarioFactory" />
>    </classes>
> </test>
> ```

You can use tags as groups for run-configuration-filter and all other TestNG and QAF features.

Comment: is it possible to convert my existing cucumber-jvm project to QAF?? (using gradle, cucumber, junit and java)