# Courgette-jvm to include project name, version and environment in the reports?

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit, courgette

I'm using `courgette-jvm` to run tests in parallel but in the reports I want to include project name, version and environmental details...

Is there any possible way to include these in courgette/cucumber reports.

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide these details by hard coding it into your Courgette runner or by passing it via system properties.

Update your Courgette runner to include:

```java
@RunWith(Courgette.class)
@CourgetteOptions(
  ...
  reportTitle = "Your project name"
  environmentInfo = "browser=chrome; git_branch=master"
)
```

or pass it via system properties:

```java
-Dcourgette.reportTitle="Your project name" 

-Dcourgette.environmentInfo="browser=chrome; git_branch=master"
```

Comment: Is there any chance to include version and env details in report!!

Comment: This feature is now available in Courgette-JVM version 5.5.0

Comment: Thanks @Prashant Ramcharan!!